# php mail form with multiple attachment with real time upload

Tags: php, javascript, upload, attachment

Im new to php. I wan a create email form for a website that can be attached multiple attachments and send mail.

I want 1 file field then i can browse image and hit upload, so it will upload and massage come beside as done. and then i should be able to upload another image. ( like gmail attachments )

can anyone help me to do this.

check this link, i want it like this

http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1473/sending-email-from-a-form-with-multiple-documents-options

( see number 6 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ready to jquery, then I have something for you.

You may use **[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)** (requires flash support) or **[AxUploader](http://www.albanx.com/)** (doesn't require flash). These uploaders has got progress bars as on Gmail. Both of them have customizable options.

Comment: youre welcome. Dont forget to mark this as answer by clicking the 'tick' icon next to this answer

Comment: this asuploader looks good. but can you help me to add this in a form which i can send a mail with this attachment. Thanks for helping

Comment: can you send me a link with full form. I could not add this in to mail form since im just new to cording. :(

Comment: post this as another question giving details. Thats how stackoverflow works.